# Sitefinity A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, radgrid, sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity 5.1 and RadGrid in this example.

I have been troubleshooting one of our pages on development server this morning and I have confirmed that it behaves differently on the page with the styling (template) than on the barebones page (no styling, no scripts etc):

1. The page does not work in Chrome but does work in IE and Firefox
2. The page on a bare-bones page (no template, header, or anything else) works in IE, Firefox and Chrome

Code used:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/services/separation-by-code/managesbyc?id={0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
```

I am using ticks to refresh the page before I get there.

Here are some results:

Firefox:
seabass.ptagis.org/services/separation-by-code/managesbyc?id=634854696522350585 -> works

Chrome on the bare-bones Sitefinity page:
seabass.ptagis.org/services/separation-by-code/managesbyc?id=634854701574768045 -> works

Chrome on the styled page (CSS, Scritps, etc):
seabass.ptagis.org/services/%2fservices%2fseparation-by-code%2fmanagesbyc%3fid%3d634854699444302751 -> nope

I get the server error attached below.

I did go through all the steps of setting web.config httprequests = 2.0 and page validations = false. That did not help.

Any help is appreciated.

> Server Error in '/' Application.   A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).   Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.   Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value
>   was detected from the client (?).   Source Error:   An unhandled
>   exception was generated during the execution of the current web
>   request. Information regarding the origin and location of the
>   exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:
>       [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +11494475
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
>   +184   Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4.0, you should be able to allow the url containing a **question-mark (?)** via the web.config

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\" />
</system.web>
```

Note, I've just removed the question-mark (?), the original default string is:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
```

Comment: You can use  requestValidationMode="2.0" also in httpRuntime

Comment: Annoyingly, the official documentation for `RequestPathInvalidCharacters` does **not** include `?` in the default set ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters?view=netframework-4.8 ) even though looking at the disassembly with RedGate Reflector shows that `?` **is** included in the defaults.