# Unable to pass a URL in GET request to a RESTful web service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, restful-url

I am stuck at an unexpected issue in my project. The issue is that there is a URL produced on the fly in my code that I have to submit it to a RESTful web service via a GET request. For e.g. the URL to submit looks like this: `http://mysampleserver.com:8080/calc/8999/bpaX`

The RESTful server accepts URL as its last parameter in the format below:

```
http://myRestfulAPI.domainname.com/capture/bbbb/http://mysampleserver.com:8080/calc/8999/bpaX
```

I also used System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(....) to encode the "URL to submit" first to incorporate it in the RESTful service call.

That resulted in getting the error below:

**System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)**

To try to resolve it, I followed [the steps described per this web page](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/f6205835-a89f-4664-93c9-da6a4dde0efb) but no luck.

I am using MVC 4 to implement the RESTful API in C#.

**Any clue or idea how to get around this showstopper issue?**

Comment: Base64 encode the URL string, perhaps?

Comment: `Uri.EscapeDataString()` should do a better job. I have had issues in the past with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` not properly encoding all characters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode. In addition you could try appending the encoded url in the query string, embedding a url inside another url seems problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two solutions I can think of.

1. Change your RESTFul service to use post, because you send information to your server, and potentially it will change your resource status, based on HTTP protocol , you should use POST anyway.
2. You can also encode your url with Base64

Answer (score 0):

The steps that you've tried are the correct steps. See also this question [potentially dangerous...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843928/sitefinity-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-clie) which is the same issue.

There are a number of characters that .NET doesn't allow in in a URL by default, and the `:` is one of them (as a query string, at least). They are 'potentially dangerous'. Making this change to the configuration file allows these characters to be passed through to your application.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Url.Encode the url in the query string (mvc parameters) otherwise it is interpreted as more URL encoding for MVC to decode as parameters.  Try something like @Url.Encode(yourStringObject) and pass it as the last value or as a query (i.e. &q=url)